# What is the function `*shellNoRender`?

Tags: angular

I searched the page of Angular.io but I have not been able to see anything, someone can tell me what to do `*shellNoRender`. For example I saw it used, so in a conference of google I/O:

```
<md-nav-list *shellNoRender>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a directive from the [app-shell](https://github.com/angular/mobile-toolkit/blob/master/guides/app-shell.md), which is part of the Angular Mobile Toolkit. This is not available in the 'normal' angular.

> There are usually components that you'd like to have in your App Shell but not your app at runtime, and vice versa. For example, we might want to have a router outlet in our dynamic application, and a progress indicator in its place in our App Shell. Fortunately, our app component already has a couple of directives available that make this simple, `*shellRender` and `*shellNoRender`.

With this you can change which component to use during runtime and during server side compilation using universal